# Ubuntu 12.04 boots to login screen but (I think) X.org crashes on login. Help Appreciated!

Tags: lightdm

I've been running Ubuntu 12.04 since it's debut in 2012 without a single problem. Today I just ran `sudo apt-key update && sudo apt-get update` and then I rebooted my computer. After rebooting however, it first shows the Ubuntu bootscreen (with the Ubuntu logo and the dots below it) after which it booted to the command line. I could login and navigate around on the command line, but no GUI was loaded at all.

So I tried running `sudo startx`, but this gave a message saying (among others) the following:

> NVIDIA: API mismatch: the NVIDIA kernel module has version 304.88, but
>   this NVIDIA driver component has version 304.108. Please make sure
>   that the kernel modle and all NVIDIA driver components have the same
>   version.

I found [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068331) which suggested to do:

```
sudo service lightdm stop # to stop the xserver
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia* # to remove all driver elements
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```

After doing this, it now boots to the login screen where it seems that there are now two users named `kramer65` on my computer. One of the two has the default (instead of my personal) background and says my password is incorrect. The other one seems to be my "real" account and  when I type my password it seems to try to show the desktop. Instead however, it shows a black screen after which I think X.org crashes, because it loads the login screen again.

So I guess the Nvidia driver is still not okay, or maybe there is something wrong with the duplicate accounts (both with a username `kramer65` (but I guess it's the Nvidia driver).

Does anybody know what else I can do from here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
The strange thing is that I can actually login using the guest account, so I don't understand whats wrong with the specific kramer65 user login.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 change to vt 1 and login, then run shell> cat /etc/passwd to check all users.

Comment: @sgx1 - When I do that, I see one user displayed that is called kramer65 as follows `kramer65:x:1000:1000:kramer65,,,:/home/kramer65:/bin/bash`. I don't know what the three comma's mean, or if this is ok at all? If this is ok, would you have any other suggestions about the Nvidia driver?

Comment: dump all log files in /var/log/lightdm to paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Try to install **gdm** once. I'm sure that **lightdm** will be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the duplicated account, but running `sudo startx` as part of your driver diagnostic / repair process has likely left a root-owned `.Xauthority` file in your home directory. The X server tries to write to this file when lightdm passes control to the user session, and if it fails the session terminates and sends control back to lightdm, causing a 'login loop'

You can go into a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd> virtual terminal, log in as your regular user (the .Xauthority file is not involved in console logins), and check with

```
ls -l ~/.{ICE,X}authority
```

(this will also list the ownership/permissions on ~/.ICEauthority, which also sometimes gets messed up). If it is root-owned then either change its ownership back

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.Xauthority
```

or simply remove it (a fresh copy will be generated on the next successful GUI session startup)

```
rm -f ~/.Xauthority
```

If that works, and allows normal GUI login from either of the apparent duplicate accounts, we can then investigate further about those.

Comment: Awesome, that indeed lets me log in again (wich was 99% of my trouble)! If you would have any idea as to how I can fix the duplicate accounts your awesomeness would reach perfection.. :)

Comment: My guess is it's something messed up in the lightdm or greeter configuration - your cat of the passwd file suggests there really isn't a duplicate account (in fact it shouldn't be possible to have accounts with the same username) but you could double check with `awk -F: '$3 > 500 {print}' /etc/passwd`. You could also post your /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and /etc/lightdm/users.conf files.